# NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.deser.BigDecimalDeserializer

Tags: java, scala, hadoop, apache-spark, jackson

`sc.newAPIHadoopRDD` is continuously giving me the error.

```
val hBaseRDD = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(hbase_conf, classOf[TableInputFormat], classOf[org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable], classOf[org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result]);


java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: ava.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.deser.BigDecimalDeserializer$.handledType()Ljava/lang/Class;
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.deser.NumberDeserializers$.<init>(ScalaNumberDeserializersModule.scala:49)
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.deser.NumberDeserializers$.<clinit>(ScalaNumberDeserializersModule.scala)
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.deser.ScalaNumberDeserializersModule$class.$init$(ScalaNumberDeserializersModule.scala:61)
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule.<init>(DefaultScalaModule.scala:20)
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule$.<init>(DefaultScalaModule.scala:37)
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule$.<clinit>(DefaultScalaModule.scala)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.<init>(RDDOperationScope.scala:82)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.<clinit>(RDDOperationScope.scala)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.withScope(SparkContext.scala:701)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.newAPIHadoopRDD(SparkContext.scala:1132)
```

I am trying to fetch values from Hbase.it is working perfectly fine in my local system already gone through many other answers related to this topic but nothing has helped me out yet.

But whenever I try to run it on my cluster it gives me error as mentioned above.

Already done all these imports

```
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormat
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.{HTableDescriptor,HColumnDescriptor}
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.{Put,HTable}
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase._
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client._
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util._
import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.{HBaseAdmin, Result}
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.{ HBaseConfiguration, HTableDescriptor }
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormat
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable
```

Followed all the steps of installation as well as classpath from

https://acadgild.com/blog/apache-spark-hbase/

Please Help me.

Comment: Maybe you are using an outdated library. You can double check that.

Comment: Outdated library of.?

Comment: You can have a look [here](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-scala). I haven't personally used it, but I think it's the right place where you can get some idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got my problem after searching and exploring other jars

```
My Hadoop Version 2.7.3
My Hbase Version 1.4.2
```

Libraries I was using was of version 1.4.2 only but straight away using them as

```
--driver-class-path $HBASE_HOME
```

As mentioned in the Link which I referred from.
But the issue was it was giving me some JARS incompatibility and also multiple occurrences of JARS with same name.
Actually the only Dependencies that are needed to run Hbase successfully are

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
            <artifactId>hbase-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
            <artifactId>hbase</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
            <artifactId>hbase-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
            <artifactId>hbase-common</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

Updated Libraries of Hbase doesnt have the required classes to implement Hbase.
After using these version of libraries it worked for me perfectly fine.